# IOS alert in background

Tags: iphone, xcode, background

My question is very simple but unfortunately I don't find any answer around the Internet.  I have an app alerts the user you amount is due based on invoice date in the database. The problem is how can I check periodically while the app in the background.  I tried beginBackgroundTaskWithName but it expires after max 10 munites and also I tried back ground fetch but it doesn't work in proper time manner, so may be it takes a day to fetch again.

I really need your help in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no reliable way of doing it on iOS. I'm interested in the answer too. Now I use background fetch in my app, but I'm thinking about remote notifications (send remote notifications, suppress them on the device, and perform a fetch instead), but I'm not sure if it's technically possible and if Apple would allow such App to the store. Does anyone know?

Comment: But I found some applications do the same what I want like data usage application, it alert you immediately if consume more than (eg 50%). How they do it?

Comment: What consumption do you mean? You mentioned a database. I suppose, it is some database on the server? If so, I think, they just check the consumption every time it changes, and when it reaches some threshold, they simply send a remote notification. It is the best solution, but it requires a server side code.

Comment: No I mean the network data consumption, like how much data you sent and received so if you consume more than50% from you data package (for example 5 GB) an alert will be immediately triggered

Comment: I'm not sure, but they might set up their own proxy, which calculates the traffic amount you've used, and sends a remote notification from server. I've heard about something like that. But may be I misunderstood something, because I don't remember for sure if it's possible to set custom proxy from an app in iOS.